# ssh -X from MAC OS to Ubuntu, error with RANDR

Tags: terminal, ssh, x11, xquartz

I have a question regarding the following situation:
I'm doing ssh -X from a Macbook with Catalina OS to an Ubuntu 16.04. I installed XQuartz-2.7.11 in the macbook in order to be able to handle the X11 and everything seems to be working. However, there are some programs that are not working as expected. 
An example is igv. If I open igv, it starts to load and opens, but it's not responsive. Menus cannot be cliked and you cannot interact with the program. Checking the log in the terminal, I think this is due to the error: "Xlib: extension "RANDR" missing on display localhost:10.0"

In the same situation but doing ssh from another Ubuntu or from Windows + VcXsrv, the program is working perfectly, without the RANDR error. So I'm fairly certain this has to do with something on the macbook or XQuartz

Any idea on how to solve it?

Thanks!